Where should **potentially** large JSON be stored?
For context, I am building a tracking database for the construction of a particle detector at CERN (my first database ever! Using postgresql with SQLAlchemy and a flask app for the upload). There will be about ~100,000 parts that will be tracked to be tested throughout the assembly. The amount of tests is unknown maybe 15-20 required tests per part but there could be reuploads that could bring it to 30-50 tests. Tests will be uploaded in the format of a JSON file and validated by pydantic.
The hard part is I do not really know how many tests or how big they will be (so I am trying to anticipate a reasonably large amount). Some could be ~1-10MB and some could be less than a KB.
The big question is do I store the JSON inside a JSONB field in a row of the database or store the large part in the cloud and the parts I want to query in the database (querying this test data would be needed! but some arrays for example obviously will not need to be queried)? Storing inside the db seems like it could reduce a lot of complexity, however this could lead to bloat. And, storing it in a cloud service is more complicated, has more points of failure but ultimately could handle large amount of data.
I have tried to do some stress testing and uploading 1/6th of the full expected data seemed pretty snappy (4KB-8KB size tests, 1million of them, locally).
If there is anybody with experience in design out there it would be great to hear some input.

In the PostgreSQL context "bloat" means a very specific thing; do you mean that bloat, or are you just concerned about the database size in general?

Oh sorry database size in general, just these arrays or strings that hold potentially a large amount of data filling up the db. Not sure what that bloat youre talking about means.

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Bloat (sensu PostgreSQL) normaĺly refers to the fact that an update is not actually an update but rather an insert of a new record and the old one is marked as deleted but not actually removed. Vacuuming is the process which deletes old records!

Ok very interesting, I have a deprecated column in my db but maybe I could just do this as deleted thing. Thank you.

Are you going to do anything with the JSON insider the database, like extract attributes or search for them?
